# Copy to clipboard via icon

Tags: javascript, html, copy, icons, clipboard

I'm using w3schools' script for copying text to clipboard when clicked, but the script only works when a textfield is present. I'm trying to have just an icon show with no textfield, so when a user clicks the icon, the coded text is automatically copied to the clipboard.

Their script is located here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

I'm using display:none; to hide the input field. Despite everything appearing to work as far as the JS is concerned, it just doesn't copy the text.

Is there a way, maybe via another method or script, that will allow me to just show an icon for copying text rather than a field + icon/link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to copy hidden inputs, but not using `display:none`, you could send the input to a location out of view, using something like `position:absolute;left:-1000px`, example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
#myInput{position:absolute;left:-1000px}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution, thank you! I honestly didn't even think about doing that! Sometimes the easiest solution is the last to be thought of. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
            var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.btn4');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.block2');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know if I understood your question, but I assumed you want to copy some text without displaying the text in your html page, with that script you are just getting the element from the id of the text imput whenever the buttom is pressed.
If you hide it you wouldnt be able to acces it. If you just want to copy some hiden text whenever you press the bottom, you should put your text in your javascript file and not into your htlm page :)

I hope my answer helped you!

Comment: This would work but not in my situation. The script itself needs to be global. The text chosen for each case (or occurrence) is set by the current page and can differ from one to the next. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

```
function copyToClipboard(text){
    var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = text;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

Comment: please provide some explanation apart from the raw code for a better answer overall.